# Is the homebrew chromium M1 optimised

Tags: homebrew, chromium, homebrew-cask, apple-m1

Is the `brew install --cask chromium` install of homebrew chromium package **optimised for M1** silicon or does it run under rosetta.

The package page doesn't offer much info on this : https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/chromium

Answer (score 8):

Sure, just look at Chromium cask code:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/chromium.rb

```
 arch = Hardware::CPU.intel? ? "Mac" : "Mac_Arm"
 ...
 url "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/#{arch}/#{version}/chrome-mac.zip
```

Checked on version:
https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Mac_Arm/948906/chrome-mac.zip

`file ~/Downloads/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium`

`Chromium: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64`

Comment: I'm really not sure why this has been downvoted since it seems to be the only answer that straightforwardly answers the question...

Comment: I needed to remove those nice apple attributes for Chromium to start `xattr -c /Applications/Chromium.app`

Comment: This answer...God help me, I was about to crack smth up, but this saved me! Just download the archive and run `xattr -c /Applications/Chromium.app` as mentioned above! - Working for M1 Max oct 2023.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is, but:

https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium

And

https://ungoogled-software.github.io/ungoogled-chromium-binaries/releases/macos/arm64/88.0.4324.150-1.1

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Simply open a terminal, cd to the executable location (for normal applications this is in /Applications/app name.app/contents/Mac OS.  Then run "file" with the executable name in this folder. The results will tell you if the executable is built for intel/arm or both.

Comment: In short, the command is: `file /Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium`